# SPI interrupt signal

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, spi, interface, protocol

My question is based on this question over [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124876/what-is-spi-interrupt-spie-in-spi-control-register#:%7E:text=The%20interrupt%20is%20raised%20by,it%20is%20ready%20for%20processing.).

I just want to clarify what is the purpose of the SPI interrupt signal. Isn't the 4 SPI clock and data lines, & chip select sufficient for the SPI interface?

Also, is the SPI interrupt signal an input or output signal?

I'm using this [module](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52056A.pdf). Want to understand whether the host (module) generates the interrupt or receives the interrupt from the slave?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @user253751. In that case, could you please help me understand the SPI interrupt with respect to the module above?

Comment: The questions do not seem to be related. Also the data sheet says the module can monitor the interrupts coming from slave chips. Does the datasheet answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPI bus does not contain an interrupt signal. But an SPI target device can route an interrupt request to the SPI bus master as a sideband signal i.e. nothing to do with the SPI bus itself.

The below diagram from your [MCP2210 Breakout Module User’s Guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52056A.pdf) illustrates this. The SPI bus and interrupt request are separate.

If any of your SPI target devices (ICs) have an interrupt request output, which they may not, they can connect it to the MCP2210 GP6 input.

From the [MCP2210 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22288a.pdf) Table 1-1, GP6 can be configured either as an interrupt input or a Chip Select output but not as General-Purpose I/O (GPIO).

The [other SE.EE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124876/what-is-spi-interrupt-spie-in-spi-control-register#:%7E:text=The%20interrupt%20is%20raised%20by,it%20is%20ready%20for%20processing.) you reference is about the internal interrupts within an SPI bus master microcontroller (MCU), as the SPI bus master peripheral interrupts the CPU within that MCU. That's different to what you're looking at in this MCP2210 documentation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! Also, very much thanks for mentioning that my question is different from the other link I posted. Also, So, if the GP6 is used as an interrupt (interrupt functionality is used), then it would be input on the device (MCP2210). If it is used as a GPO or CS, then GP6 would be the output. Am I correct?

Comment: @Newbie, please see revision to answer a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupt signals have nothing to do with SPI. This SPI-to-USB adapter *also* receives an interrupt signal, in case you need it. Many devices that have an SPI bus also generate interrupts, and this adapter can tell the computer there was an interrupt.

If you don't need it, you don't have to use it. In this case you can use the interrupt pin (GP6) as a chip select pin, a general-purpose pin, or nothing, as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, if the GP6 is used as an interrupt (interrupt functionality is used), then it would be input on the device (MCP2210). If it is used as a GPO or CS, then GP6 would be the output. Am I correct?

Comment: @Newbie that's how I understand it. The MCP2210 **chip**'s data sheet probably has more details.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!